# Применение слова "ресурс" в отношении работник-работодатель?

Tags: фразеология

Можно назвать собственника (работодателя) предприятия ресурсом, работника этой организации? Необходимо развернутое мнение специалиста, а не просто да/нет.

Comment: Поясните, пожалуйста, вопрос: что именно  вас интересует - можно ли работодателя назвать работником или же ресурсом?

Comment: Может ли работник, назвать своего работодателя, ресурсом, по отношению к себе?

Comment: @Смайлер, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Слово ресурс имеет следующие значения:

[image]

В экономике есть термин "трудовые ресурсы''. Под этим термином понимается ''совокупная рабочая сила''. А человек, как рабочая сила, является важнейшим ресурсом организации. Но это обобщенно. Из этого следует, что работодатель не является ресурсом по отношению к работнику.

Comment: Спасибо! Википедия, мне подобное объяснение дала!